# Eliminar fila de jTable con el id de la fila

Tags: java

tengo un jTable puedo eliminar la fila sin problema con la siguiente función:

```
int fila = tabla.getSelectedRow();
        if (fila >= 0) {
            m.removeRow(fila);
        }
```

con eso elimino la fila seleccionada no hay problema, el problema es que no se como identificar la fila en la cual se encuentra ubicado el registro "Daniel", es decir tengo una tabla con lo siguiente:

```
ID|Nombre|Direccion
1|Carlos|Av.las manzanas
2|Maria|Av.las100
3|Daniel|Av.Loque sea
```

es decir quiero eliminar la fila en la cual se encuentra el Id3, pero ese id es el id que tiene el nombre "Daniel "en la base de datos, es decir que en la tabla el numero de fila seria el numero 2,

es posible eliminar la fila indicándole el valor , algo así como en sql, pero no se como podría hacerlo en java

```
Delete fila where idPersona=1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo un `TableModel` o derivado llamado `m` el método encargado de borrar las filas que contengan un determinado string sería algo así:

```
public void borrarFilasCon(String nombre)
 {
    for (int f = 0; f < m.getRowCount(); f++)
    {
      for(int c = 0; c < m.getColumnCount(); c++)
      {
        if (m.getValueAt(f, c).equals(nombre)) 
        {
          m.removeRow(f);

        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: amigo muchas gracias por su respuesta es justo lo que necesitaba saludos

Answer (score 2):

Yo primero te recomendaría implementar 2 métodos en tu clase de conexión que te servirán de mucho.
Los métodos getSt() y getCon() de la siguiente manera:

```
public conexion(){
    try{
        Class.forName(drv);
        ct = DriverManager.getConnection(db, user, pass);
        st = ct.createStatement();
        //System.out.println("Conexión exitosa");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error de conexión");
                    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public Statement getSt(){
    return st;
}

    public Connection getCon(){
            return ct;
}
```

Luego, en donde tienes tu tabla, puedes ejecutar este código

```
//Se crea una instancia de la clase conexion
conexion cc = new conexion();//al inicio de la clase

public void tuMetodo(){
int filsel = tuTabla.getSelectedRow();
    if(filsel == -1){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensajeTabla);
    }else{
        try {
            TableModel m = tuTabla.getModel();
            for(int i = 0; i<m.getRowCount(); i++){
                //Se toman los datos de la tabla cliente
                int id = (int) m.getValueAt(filsel, 0);//suponiendo que el id lo muestras en la primera columna
                String sql="SELECT * FROM tablaBD WHERE ID = '" + id + "'";
                ResultSet rs = cc.getSt().executeQuery(sql);
                if(rs.next()){
                    String sql2="TU CONSULTA PARA ELIMINAR WHERE ID = '" + id + "'";
                    Statement st = cc.getCon().createStatement();
                    st.executeUpdate(sql2);
                    st.close();
                }
                m.removeRow(filsel);
            }//fin del for

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}//Fin de tuMetodo
```

Así eliminarás, tanto de tu base de datos como de tu JTable, el registro que seleccionaste